# Get symbolic output in IPython console

Tags: python, console, sympy, spyder

Using this code in Spyder 4.2.5 with IPython 8.2.0:

```
from sympy import init_printing, symbols
from sympy import sqrt, diff

init_printing()
x = symbols('x')

g = 1 - x
u = sqrt(g)

h = 1 + x
v = sqrt(h)

y = u / v
y_d = diff(y)
print(y_d)   # <--- prints text mode in IPython console
display(y_d) # <--- outputs a picture in Plots
```

[image]

I'd like to print the symbolic output on the IPython console. I tried:

- `print` but it outputs a text.
- `display` but while it outputs a symbolic output, this output goes to the `Plot` tab.

So I'm looking for a combination of the two. A symbolic output can be displayed in the console, as visible on the picture, by typing `y_d` at the console prompt. What is the equivalent Python instruction?

Comment: Please, clarify: if you type `y_d` on a cell, do you want to get text output?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Anyway, `init_printing` is the SymPy function that allows to customize how a symbolic expression is rendered on the screen.

Comment: @Davide_sd: On the picture there is an output labeled `console mode output`. I want to know what Python instruction I can use in the code to produce the same output at the same place.

Comment: You could uncheck the mute inline plotting option in the Spyder plots pane: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/plots.html#mute-inline-plotting

Comment: @rhkarls: Yes that works, all `display` outputs now go to the console.